# PHP Display a unix timestamp in GMT

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I have a unix timestamp stored in mysql of:

```
1438919940
```

which when I convert it at http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm it displays as

```
Fri, 07 Aug 2015 03:59:00 GMT // this is how I want to display it
```

In my code I am displaying it using:

```
$published = $row['update_date'];  //this is where 1438919940 comes from
$published = date ('jS F y @ g:ia',$published);
echo $published;
```

but this displays as

```
7th August 15 @ 3:59am
```

The original strtotime I did was a PDT time and my server is set to Europe/London and in my script I have

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

How are the online conversion site echoing that to the 'correct' (how I want it) version and I'm getting a date in the future!!

Comment: Store the date and time within GMT format and change the timezone as per user timezone runtime

Comment: How are you getting a date in the future? Its the same 7th august 2015, 3:59am ? Perhaps you need "gmdate" instead of just "date" ?

Answer (score 3):

Please try

```
date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
$published = $row['update_date'];
$published = date ('D, d M Y H:i:s T',$published);
echo $published;
```

Please refer to the following link for the date formats: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Welcome to SE! This looks like a good/correct answer. However, I think it might be improved a bit by adding a e.g. small explanation about the format specifiers and/or a link to a reference explaining it.

Comment: thanks andreas for the suggestions.

Comment: GMT and UTC are the same.

Comment: @DeniGeorge it now displays as Fri, 07 Aug 2015 03:59:00 GMT - again that's tomorrow!!

Comment: Sorry @DeniGeorge the point I'm making is that the date is displaying as a date in the future.   It's come from a pubDate in an rss feed that is in a PDT time

Comment: The result is correct. See e.g. http://www.unixtimestamp.com/ : 1438919940
Is equivalent to:
08/07/2015 @ 3:59am (UTC) Whether that date is in the future or not is irrelevant. It is the time corresponding to the timestamp.

Comment: Yep, I just figured that too - thanks.   I will look at how the timestamp is being generated.